# Projection onto Form factors in the on-shell case

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-matrices

I need to calculate a vertex $$\Gamma^\mu=F_1 \gamma^\mu + \frac{i}{2m}F_2 \sigma^{\mu\nu} k_\nu$$ The vertex contains propagators, which I have taken on-shell with Cutkosky rules. The problem when I extract the form factors with $$ F_1=\frac{1}{16} \text{Trace}[\Gamma^\mu\gamma_\mu] $$ is that the on-shell properties are not properly taken into account. It should not make a difference if I use on-shell forms of propagators and vertices in $\Gamma^\mu$ or the general ones, which are the same in the on-shell case, but if I calculate like this, it makes a difference. I have seen stuff like
$$(\gamma \cdot p'+m)/(2m)\Gamma^\mu(\gamma \cdot p+m)/(2m)$$, but if I try calculating $$ F_1=\frac{1}{16} \text{Trace}[(\gamma \cdot p'+m)/(2m)\Gamma^\mu (\gamma \cdot p+m)/(2m)\gamma_\mu] $$ it again does depend on if I calculate with the on-shell or off-shell form even though it should give the same result. So how do I properly calculate this?